# Escape forward slash in branch name in go.mod?

Tags: go, go-modules

Currently in go.mod, for a dependency you can provide a version tag or a commit ID or a branch name. However, if the branch name contains a forward slash (`/`) then `go mod vendor` complains `invalid: disallowed version string`.
Is there a way to escape this forward slash in the branch name so that `go mod` commands will continue to work?

I want to avoid using commit ID or version tag because I am working on development branches in multiple modules that are continuously changing, so I don't want to constantly update go.mod to use the new commit ID. And since these are development branches we don't have a release tag for them yet.

Comment: Specifying a branch is exactly the same as specifying the HEAD commit from said branch.

Comment: @JimB yes but the difference is when I run `go mod vendor` and I have specified the branch it will automatically pull the HEAD commit of that branch but that doesn't happen when the commit ID is provided.

Comment: Just do not use / in branch names? Or: Do not depend on branches? What type of "dependency" is that if it is dependent on a named branch (and thus probably a moving target?

Comment: How are you specifying a bare branch? When [using a branch version](https://go.dev/ref/mod#version-queries) (which cannot match any other version strings, which is why it can't have a `/`) it must be written to `go.mod` in a pseudo-version format corresponding to a specific commit.

Comment: @JimB I know that even if you provide branch name it automatically converts it to the pseudo version but every time the code of my dependency changes I want to just provide the branch name and run `go mod vendor` rather than calculating the pseudo version or finding out the commit ID.

Comment: @Volker Unfortunately, the remote build systems that we use force us to use that kind of branch naming scheme. And the dependency is a moving target because it is also in development.

Comment: If you have the repo checked out, you can quickly get the commit via `git rev-parse --short branch_name`. Otherwise, the branch names you have are not compatible with this type of version query.

Comment: Exactly, I don't want to keep that repo locally.

Comment: This has always "just worked" for me, but today one of my coworkers got the `disallowed version string` error from Go 1.19 on Windows when the exact same command worked for me with Go 1.18 on Linux. So I'd love to know what the exact conditions that cause Go to reject `/` actually are.